# How to get the current index during recursive call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ancestry

I use the gem `ancestry` to create comments.

Now, I can list all comments.

But I want to push serial number to each comment.

For example, if there were 3 comments, the first comment is annotated by 1, the next annotated by 2,..

I have no idea how to do it?

### show.html.haml

```
- if notice
  %p.alert.alert-success= notice
= nested_comments(@comment.subtree.arrange(:order => :created_at))
```

### helper

```
  def nested_comments(comments)
    if comments.respond_to? :map
      comments.map do |comment, sub_comments|
        render(comment) + content_tag(:div, nested_comments(sub_comments), :class => "nested_comments")
      end.join.html_safe
    end
  end
```

### each_with_index won't work on recursive

if I have 4 comments, I want to show 0,1,2,3 for each comment

But each_with_index can not make it because it's a recursive call.

```
comments.each_with_index.map do |(comment, sub_comments), i|
```

### comments

```
=> {#<Comment id: 2, user_id: 1, ip: nil, content: "I'm id2 the second floor VIVOTEK Releases New Vers...", commentable_id: nil, commentable_type: nil, created_at: "2014-11-07 03:59:38", updated_at: "2014-11-07 06:56:12", ancestry: nil>=>
  {#<Comment id: 4, user_id: 1, ip: nil, content: "lala", commentable_id: nil, commentable_type: nil, created_at: "2014-11-07 05:22:41", updated_at: "2014-11-07 05:22:41", ancestry: "2">=>
    {#<Comment id: 5, user_id: 1, ip: nil, content: "son of 4", commentable_id: nil, commentable_type: nil, created_at: "2014-11-07 06:38:04", updated_at: "2014-11-07 06:38:04", ancestry: "2/4">=>
      {},
     #<Comment id: 6, user_id: 1, ip: nil, content: "dild last 252", commentable_id: nil, commentable_type: nil, created_at: "2014-11-07 06:52:15", updated_at: "2014-11-07 06:52:15", ancestry: "2/4">=>
      {}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every enumerable instance in ruby has a method [`each_with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index), providing `an_enumerator`. So in your case I would suggest to use:

```
- comments.map do |comment, sub_comments|
+ comments.each_with_index.map do |idx, comment, sub_comments|
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with_index` with map

```
comments.map.with_index do |comment, sub_comments, index|
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an elegant solution.  But you could pass a counter into your `nested_comments` function, and deal with the problem manually -- which might well mean without `map` at all. Ugly, I know.

To take a simpler example, should you need one:

```
def nested_foo(result, string, index)
  index += 1
  result << "\n#{index}: #{string}"

  if index >= 10
    return result
  else
    return nested_foo(result, string, index)
  end

end
```